# Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery' Angular6

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular6

i have below error when i use jQuery in TypeScript Angular6 please help me this

```
jQuery('#assignsp').modal('show');
```

following these steps

3 Steps:

Install jQuery. (skip if already installed)

npm install jquery --save
Install types for jQuery.

npm install @types/jquery --save

```
Import jQuery in app.module.ts.

import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

its show me Error

error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type '`JQuery<HTMLElement>`

> error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

Comment: Emh.. why are you using Jquery with typescript?..

Comment: then show to handel bootstrap model in typescript

Comment: model show and hide  from typescript

Comment: You can simply create a modal by code and then hide/show it by using `ngIf`. I can show you an example if you want. but directly using jQuery in typescript is a very bad pratcise

Comment: Why don't you use this **(<any>$('#assignsp')).modal('show');** in your code

Comment: when i use ngif model does not distory

Comment: @fizakhan its not working i was try

Comment: ERROR TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: its show me this error @fiza

Comment: are you trying to open a modal of bootstrap 3/4 with jQuery? Did you try ngx-bootstrap?

Answer (score 7):

There is multiple things you were trying to do at same time. First, you need to integrate jQuery with typescript and second, integration of bootstrap modal functionality which eventually has an dependency on jQuery. Lets integrate jQuery first and than will jump on to the bootstrap.

jQuery Installation: you have already done many of things here already

```
npm install jquery --save

npm install @types/jquery --save

npm i bootstrap --save
```

Angular configuration: make an entry of jQuery and bootstrap here:

```
"styles":[
           "src/styles.css",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         ],
"scripts":[
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
             "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
           ]
```

Typescript configuration: add this lines at top of your component.

```
/// <reference path ="../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts"/>
declare var $: any 
ngOnInit() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

HTML: add modal code here

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal content
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried above way and its working for me. Let me know if you still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import * as $AB from 'jquery';
        jQuery('#exampleModal').show();
   jQuery('#exampleModal').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue and i have done below steps and it got resolved.

```html
npm install -D @types/bootstrap --save

in your app.module.ts
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import * as $ from "jquery";
```